# Executing SSIS package gives System.IO.IOException

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am trying to execute the package and every time I see the following error. Especially when I execute the data flow task.

*Error :*

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 
>           'C:\PPE_OVERRIDES.ispac' because it is being used by another process.

*Full Output:*

```
------ Build started: Project: PPE_OVERRIDES, Configuration: Development ------
    Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Incremental ...
    Starting project consistency check ...
    Project consistency check completed. The project is consistent.
    Error : System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 
        'C:\PPE_OVERRIDES.ispac' because it is being used by another process.
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
       at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
       at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
    Build complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

How can I fix it. My ispac file is in bin folder. I want to make sure the SsISDB catalog and Visual Studio are not fighting over this location

Answer (score 7):

Based on the following article:

- [Fix SSIS Error while execution: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file ‘PATH\Project.ispac’ because it is being used by another process.](https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/22/fix-ssis-error-while-execution-system-io-ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-pathproject-ispac-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/)

*Possible Solution:*

> Need to kill the Windows processes (SSIS Debug Host, and SSIS Debug Host (32 bit)) related to SSIS Debug and restart Visaul Studio to address the problem.

[image]

**Similar Issue links**

- [The process cannot access the file 'ssisproject.ispac' because it is being used by another process.](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-process-cannot-acces-file.html)
- [SSIS: The process cannot access the file ‘*.ispac’ because it is being used by another process](https://ajitpatra.com/2018/03/29/ssis-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-ispac-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/)
- [SIS: The process cannot access the file ‘*.ispac’ because it is being used by another process](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/ajitpatra365crm/archive/2018/03/29/ssis-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-ispac-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

Comment: Tried this many time it doesnt fix this issue. I deleted whole thing and started new project still i am encountering

Comment: @user10260750 try to copy the visual studio solution to another directory and try again, if it didn't works then it is not related to SSISDB

Comment: @user10260750 in addition are you running windows using an administrator (can you see all running processes)?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you start up an instance of SQL Server Manager, you have to go kill the SSIS Debug Host processes. However, I don't think they showed up until I tried to re-execute a package. I might try executing an empty, dummy package, fix the crash, then try again with the real package.